# maven builds fails inside ubuntu vagrant machine as well as docker instance

Tags: java, maven, docker, vagrant

I am developing an api using jaxb. The maven build (using jdk-7) works on my local windows machine. Now if I try to build it on my vagrant box (ubuntu/trusty64) after setting up maven and openjdk7 on the vm, I get following error on performing mvn clean install:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException (operation not permitted)

There are in all 5 projects as part of my pom.xml, the first 3 (business and projects) gets built successfully, only the 4th one (which generates the war) file fails with this error when it is trying to generate the war file. Maven was successful in copying other files into the target folder for other projects.

Also, I am able to do perform maven builds on the same machine without errors on simple java projects (from https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html)

My guess is the Vagrant Virtualbox VM is not is not able to allocate required resources to JVM but i am clueless on how i could do it. I did try to increase the memory footprint by setting the maven properties on my vm

> export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx4096m -XX:PermSize=1024m"

Detailed error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.4:war (default-war) on project '<app>' : Could not copy webapp classes [/usr/src/<app>/target/classes]: /usr/src/<app>/target/<app>-03.00.00.01-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/<my-app-src>/rest/config/ResourceConfig.class (Operation not permitted) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.4:war (default-war) on project <my-app>: Could not copy webapp classes [/vagrant_data/<my-app-src>/<my-app>/target/classes]
[/vagrant_data/<my-app-src>/<my-app>/target/classes]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Could not copy webapp classes [/vagrant_data/<my-apps-src>/target/classes]
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.packaging.ClassesPackagingTask.performPackaging(ClassesPackagingTask.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.packaging.WarProjectPackagingTask.handleClassesDirectory(WarProjectPackagingTask.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.packaging.WarProjectPackagingTask.performPackaging(WarProjectPackagingTask.java:104)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.AbstractWarMojo.buildWebapp(AbstractWarMojo.java:505)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.AbstractWarMojo.buildExplodedWebapp(AbstractWarMojo.java:433)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo.performPackaging(WarMojo.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo.execute(WarMojo.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /vagrant_data/<my-apps-src>/target/<my-app>-03.00.00.01-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/<my-app-src>/rest/config/ResourceConfig.class (Operation not permitted)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:160)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.FileUtils.doCopyFile(FileUtils.java:1068)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1049)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.packaging.AbstractWarPackagingTask.copyFile(AbstractWarPackagingTask.java:334)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.packaging.AbstractWarPackagingTask$1.registered(AbstractWarPackagingTask.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.util.WebappStructure.registerFile(WebappStructure.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.packaging.AbstractWarPackagingTask.copyFile(AbstractWarPackagingTask.java:149)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.packaging.AbstractWarPackagingTask.copyFiles(AbstractWarPackagingTask.java:104)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.packaging.ClassesPackagingTask.performPackaging(ClassesPackagingTask.java:75)
    ... 27 more
```

Comment: Are `<my-app-src>` and `<my-app>` oscurated by you in the pasted output?

Comment: yes... the app has details about the company I am working in (in its namespace)

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you don't have permision to write in that folder.
you could try using chmod 777 . -R in the vagrant shared folder. Also before doing this you could check if you can create a new file in the target directory by "touch target/newFile".

Comment: i realized i didnt post enough information so i have edited my question with more details. The maven build is able to copy many other files into the target folder  and I was able to even perform touch newFile into the 'target' folder. I see classes and other folders in the target folder.

And like I said, maven build of a simple app from https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html works without issues

Comment: i see that you use windows, could you restart the windows OS, then open up vagrant without opening any other ide that might hold the lock for files. Windows has a problem with removing/ overwriting opened files.

Comment: i didnt reboot my machine yet, but if i perform maven build on the same folder (the folder that is being used as synched folder) through my windows command prompt, the build works.