# JAVA build: overcoming file path length limit issue in linux

Tags: java, linux

I am trying to build my java application in linux but because of several long namespaces being used, the target war files are being generated with their folder path going over 255 character limit. How can i fix this issue so the build does not fail because of path length?
I get IOException with operation not permitted when the javac compiler tries to compile files going over 255 character limit in their path

Comment: Please add whole stacktrace?

Comment: How are you trying to build your project? Do you use Ant?

Comment: The stack trace and details are posted in another question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32319790/maven-builds-fails-inside-ubuntu-vagrant-machine-as-well-as-docker-instance The reason for this issue was the same filepath issue I am referring to in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32319790/maven-builds-fails-inside-ubuntu-vagrant-machine-as-well-as-docker-instance